# redshift copy using amazon pipeline fails for missing primary key

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a set of files on S3 that I am trying to load into redshift.
I am using the amazon data pipeline to do it. the wizard took the cluster, db and file format info but I get errors that a primary key is needed to keep existing fields in th table (`KEEP_EXISTING`) on the table

**My table schema is:**

```
create table public.Bens_Analytics_IP_To_FileName(  
Day date not null encode delta32k,  
IP varchar(30) not null encode text255,  
FileName varchar(300) not null encode text32k,  
Count integer not null)  
distkey(Day)  
sortkey(Day,IP);
```

so then I added a composite primary key on the table to see if it will work, but I get the same error.

```
create table public.Bens_Analytics_IP_To_FileName(  
Day date not null encode delta32k,  
IP varchar(30) not null encode text255,  
FileName varchar(300) not null encode text32k,  
Count integer not null,  
primary key(Day,IP,FileName))  
distkey(Day)  
sortkey(Day,IP);
```

So I decided to add an identity column as  the last column and made it the primary key but then the COPY operation wants a value in the input files for that identity column which did not make much sense

ideally I want it to work without a primary key or a composite primary key

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not in a great condition. They have added a 'mergeKey' concept that can be any arbitrary key ([announcement](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2634), [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftcopyactivity.html)). You should not have to define a primary key on table with this.

But you would still need to supply a key to perform join between your new data coming in and the existing data in redshift table.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Pipeline, under Parameters, there is a field named: `myPrimaryKeys (optional)`. Enter you Pk there, instead of adding it to your table definition.